# Design Android APK signing server

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails-3, apk, signing

I was recently given a task to design/implement/maintain an Android APK signing server.  I had never done that in the past and will probably do it in Rails (my organization is a Rails shop).

This signing server basically takes an APK given by the build, and signs it with a protected and secure certificate. And this signing server shouldn't allow any access to outside except restricted to a particular IP address.

I don't have any experience writing a signing server. Would anybody who had done that share their experiences and some of the design patterns on how to design it, so it's secure and protected?

Answer (score 2):

Restricting by IP is definitely not enough, use at least some form of username/password authentication and keep an audit log, so you know who signed what and when. If you are doing this in vanilla Ruby, saving the APK to a file and invoking `jarsigner` as a shell command is probably the easiest way to do it. If you are using JRuby, you can use Java APIs to do the actual signing.

You also need to make sure *only* your webapp can read the signing key, at the very least. If you have many keys you need to let users select which key to use or give them a key based on group, etc. (one for the games department, one for the music apps department, etc.). You might want to also consider storing the keys in an HSM or a smart card to make sure they cannot be extracted from the server. Still if someone hacks it, they will be able to sign apps, but not steal the actual keys (which cannot be revoked).

Answer (score 1):

The process of signing an APK is not super complicated. However; the security of the server would be the hardest part of yoru task. Simply put, you should have the credentials either on your server or somewhere so that you can sign the apk (ideally this is secure).

A good place to learn this process is:
http://developer.android.com/tools/building/index.html

Comment: Thanks! I had done it locally, but we have a big scale production shop here which needs to write a signing server for it. The Android reference is what we used to write our local script, but we are looking to build a signing server for it.

Any design suggestion?

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution to this yet?